# How can I remove additional html object on a page

Tags: javascript, html, head

for some very hard reason i get inserted additional ... before the beggining of my page, before my real `<head>` starts. This comes from another app i cant remove it.

So the code looks like this:

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="http://www.facebook.com/#!/nagradnaigra123.si?sk=app_163054567105477">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
<!DOCTYPE html
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xml:lang="en" lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
... normal content from here on...
```

So im asking how on earth can i remove the additional head on the begginig of my page. i can edit css, add javascript, jquery, php... but i just dont know the solution to this problem.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: What code is generating this page?

Answer (score 0):

Take the body tags out of the head.

Should be

```
<head>
stuff
<title>Object moved</title>
</head>

<body>
stuff
<h2>Object moved to <a href="http://www.facebook.com/#!/nagradnaigra123.si?sk=app_163054567105477">here</a>.</h2>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first `<title>` and `<h2>` tags by putting the code below in your `<head>`. This will make the extra `<html>` tag at the beginning have no effect on your page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var e = document.getElementsByTagName( 'title' );
    e[0].parentNode.removeChild( e[0] );
    e = document.getElementsByTagName( 'h2' );
    e[0].parentNode.removeChild( e[0] );
</script>
```

Works in FireFox, didn't test in other browsers.